# Confusion over Encryption System Logic (Modular Arithmetic)

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am reading [Homomorphic Encryption and the Approximate GCD Problem](http://tigerprints.clemson.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2281&context=all_dissertations), specifically Section 3.2 on page 23, which outlines a basic encryption scheme:

> The user chooses a large odd integer $p$ to be the secret key for the system.
>
> A plaintext is a single bit $m$.  To encrypt a message $m\in\{0,1\}$ and obtain a ciphertext $c$, the user chooses $q,e \in\mathbb{Z}$ independently and randomly from some distribution for each encryption and computes $$E(m,p) =qp+ 2e+m$$
>
> The binary size of $q$ is generally chosen to be greater than the binary size of $p$. The binary size of $e$, which is referred to as the error, is much smaller than the binary size of $p$. We will discuss the exact sizes for these parameters later on.
>
> The decryption function for this system is given by
>   $$D(c,p) = (c\mod p)\mod 2$$
>
> To see that the decryption function is correct for a ciphertext $c=qp+ 2e+m$, observe that
>   \begin{align}D(c,p) &= (qp+ 2e+m\mod p)\mod 2
> \\&= (2e+m)\mod 2\\
> &=m \end{align}
>
> Note that for this to work we need \begin{align}2|e|+ 1&<\frac p2\\|e|&<\frac p4−\frac 12\end{align} so that $(2e+m\mod p) = 2e+m$.

However, what I am struggling with is, if we choose $e<0$ then \begin{align}2e+m\mod p &= (p-2|e|)+m\\&\neq2e+m\end{align} by the definition of modulo (at least as seen by most common programming languages):

> $a\mod b=r$ where $a=qb+r$ and $0\leq r<b$

Since $p$ is specified to be odd, then we have 
\begin{align}&((p-2|e|)+m)\mod 2 \\
&=((p\mod2)-((2|e|)\mod 2))+(m\mod 2)\mod 2\\
&= ((1-0)+m)\mod2\tag{as $p$ is odd}\\
&= (1+m)\mod 2\tag{as $m$ is either $1$ or $0$}\\
&\neq m\end{align}

I'm just trying to understand why we specify $$|e|<\frac p4 - \frac 12$$ and not $$0<e<\frac p4 - \frac 12$$

as, as far as I understand, the decryption doesn't work when \begin{align}0<-e&<\frac p4 - \frac 12\\
\frac 12 - \frac p4 < e &< 0
\end{align}

> **Example**
>
> Choose $p=1583$, $q=52498$, then $|e|<\frac{1583}{4}-\frac 12 = 395.25$ so choose $e=-241$
>
> For $m=1$, we have \begin{align}c&=52498\times 1583+2\times (-241)+1\\
> &= 83104334-482+1\\
> &= 83103853\end{align}
>
> We decrypt this as follows \begin{align}D(c,p)&=(c\mod p)\mod 2\\
> &= (83103853\mod 1583) \mod 2\\
> &= 1102 \mod 2\\
> &= 0\\
> &\neq m=1\end{align}
>
> We can see that \begin{align}(c\mod p) &= 1102\\
> &= (2\times 550.5) + 1\end{align} and $550.5 > 395.25$ which doesn't satisfy the constraint on $|e|$

---

Can someone either confirm that my logic is correct, or explain to me where it is falling apart please.

Comment: Note: I also asked this on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44944/homomorphic-encryption-and-the-approximate-gcd-problem-confusion)

Answer (score 0):

You made a couple of mistakes when you wrote this:

\begin{align}2e+m\mod p &= p-(2e+m)\\&\neq2e+m\end{align}

First of all, you seem to be assuming $e$ is negative on the left and positive on the right.  Second, you subtracted $m$ as well as $2e$, but $m$ is always non-negative.  The correct expression should be

\begin{align}2e+m\mod p &= (p-2|e|)+m\end{align}

You should be able to work out the rest.

INCIDENTALLY: Do NOT go by 'nearly all programming languages' when using modulo arithmetic in a purely mathematical context.  The expression

\begin{align}n\mod p\end{align}

ALWAYS means the value $r$ between 0 [inclusive] and p [exclusive] such that $n - r$ is divisible by $p$, even when $n$ is negative.

Comment: I've corrected my definition of $2e+m\mod p$ however, I'm still seeing the same problem, that then $(p-2|e|)+m)\mod2\neq m$

Comment: Also, I'm not suing this in a purely mathematical context, it is an encryption scheme, hence is designed to be programmed which is why I refer to the definition of modulus in programming languages. Incidentally, this is the same as the pure mathematical definition though

Comment: For reference, it has been pointed out to me that they define modulo as follows in the linked text: $a\bmod p\;\;$ denotes reducing $a$ modulo $p$ into the interval $(-p/2, p/2]$